# Same ethernet cards, same firmware, same drivers ... different Advertising Mode

Tags: networking, network-speed, ethtool

I have a strange issue.
Having same cards, same drivers and same updated version of ethtool on 2 different OS, (XenServer7.* and centOS7.3).

if I run on centOS ethtool on the card I get:

```
 Supported ports: [ FIBRE Backplane ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                40000baseKR4/Full
                                40000baseCR4/Full
                                40000baseSR4/Full
                                40000baseLR4/Full
                                56000baseKR4/Full
                                100000baseKR4/Full
                                100000baseSR4/Full
                                100000baseCR4/Full
                                100000baseLR4_ER4/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                40000baseKR4/Full
                                40000baseCR4/Full
                                40000baseSR4/Full
                                40000baseLR4/Full
                                56000baseKR4/Full
                                100000baseKR4/Full
                                100000baseSR4/Full
                                100000baseCR4/Full
                                100000baseLR4_ER4/Full
```

While if I run the same command on the XenServer I get:

```
 Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
                                1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                40000baseKR4/Full
                                40000baseCR4/Full
                                40000baseSR4/Full
                                40000baseLR4/Full
                                56000baseKR4/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full
                                1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                40000baseKR4/Full
                                40000baseCR4/Full
                                40000baseSR4/Full
                                40000baseLR4/Full
                                56000baseKR4/Full
```

The **56000baseKR4/Full** link mode appears **only** after upgrading ethtool.
However seems that XenServer cannot see the following advertising methods:

```
                            100000baseKR4/Full
                            100000baseSR4/Full
                            100000baseCR4/Full
                            100000baseLR4_ER4/Full
```

I have already checked ethtool and firmware on the card.
They are the same as in the centOS, but XenServer won't advertise a 100000 link mode.

Comment: Being two different, albeit similar, Linux distribution, both kernel and userspace can differ in subtle ways.

Comment: of course... but... did you notice something I miss to check?
Some drivers I shoulded update before go?

Comment: Give a look at kernel version, issuing `uname -a` on both machines. If the driver is compiled as a kernel module, check its version.

Comment: Driver is the same:
`driver: mlx5_core
version: 4.0-2.0.0 (28 Mar 2017)
firmware-version: 12.17.2020`
Same on the 2 server.

XenServer have of locked kernel to `3.10.0+10`